# MIPS Quicksort program showing Exception 4 [Address Error in inst/data fetch ]

Tags: assembly, mips

I am learning MIPS . I tried to write a program on Quicksort (without recursion).
I wrote the following code . It takes sorted array number of elements and number to search as input , returns the array index of the number ,

```
.data
    .align 2
    myArray: .space 4000    #1000 elements atmost
prompt1: .asciiz "Enter n : "
prompt2: .asciiz " "
prompt3: .asciiz "\nEnter Sorted Array: "
prompt4: .asciiz "Enter number to be sorted"

.text

main:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt1
    syscall

    li $v0, 5
    syscall


    move $s1, $v0,    #n
    addi $s0, $s1, -1 

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt4
    syscall

    li $v0, 5
    syscall        

    move $s2, $v0    #stores k ,  number to be searched


addi $t0, $zero, 0        #clear values in $t0


    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt3
    syscall

input:


    li $v0, 5           # reading inputs
    syscall

    add $t1, $t0, $zero


    add $t3, $v0, $zero

    sll $t1, $t0, 2

    sw $t3, myArray($t1)
    addi $t0, $t0, 1    
    slt $t1, $s0, $t0

    beq $t1, $zero, input


    addi $t0, $zero, 0  # $t0 stores left
    sll $t1, $s0, 2     #t1 stores right    
    add $t2, $t1, $t0   
    srl $t2, $t2, 1     # $t2 stores mid


    BinSearch:

    bge $t0, $t1 , exit 

    lw $t6, myArray($t2)        #showing Error here

    blt $t6, $s2, leftindex      # if(A[mid]<k) goto left

    beq $t6, $s2, found

    bgt $t6, $t2, rightindex


    leftindex:
    addi    $t0, $t2, 1     # left index leftindex= mid + 1
    add $t2, $t1, $t0       # mid = left + right 
    srl $t2, $t2, 1         # mid/2
    j BinSearch             #goback to Binary Search 

    found:
    li $v0, 1               #if(A[leftindex]==k)
    addi $a0, $t0, 0        #print index of k
    syscall
    j exit                  #exit programme

    rightindex:             
    addi $t1, $t2, -1   #rightindex = mid -1
    add $t2, $t1, $t0   #mid = left+right
    srl $t2, $t2, 1     #mid/2 
    j BinSearch         #goback to binarysearch


    exit:

    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

It is giving me error : Exception 4 [Adderess Error in inst/data fetch ]

It is giving me error in line  70-72 which is

```
    lw $t6, myArray($t2)

    blt $t6, $s2, leftindex
```

I have mentioned the line as comment in code also

Please tell me what I am doing wrong .

Comment: Means your `$t2` value is wrong. Single step the code and see why.

Comment: I corrected that. the $t2 is index number of array, I need to multiply it by 4 , because of 4 bit per index in mips . still its not working .
any other mistake you can spot ?

Comment: Define "not working", and as before, single step your code and see where it stops working.